# ngFilter equals with 2 var in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-filter

I have a little problem, I would like to do a equals with 2 var in ngFilter. I try lot of combinaison, but it doesn't work...

I get the first var here, in $routeParams

```
function ANNAnnonceListe(DBManager, $routeParams) {
var ici = this;
this.annonces_ar = [];
this.idLieu = $routeParams.idLieu;

DBManager.all('ANNAnnonce')
    .then(function (annonces) {
        console.log(annonces);
        ici.annonces_ar = annonces;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

the second here :

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.annonces_ar | filter: {value.id : vm.idLieu_nb} ">
    {{value.nom_str}}
    {{value.idLieu_nb}}
</div>
```

i would like this equality (vm.idLieu = value.id_nb) and display if is true

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be property name directly `id_nb` instead of `value.id`. Also have `: true` parameter at the end of your filter to perform exact check, inspite of contains check.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.annonces_ar | filter: { idLieu_nb : vm.idLieu}: true ">
    {{value.nom_str}}
    {{value.idLieu_nb}}
</div>
```

Comment: Ok sorry.. I have a array with 5 entries (Poker 1, Billard 1, Rami 1, Billard 2, 
Chifoumi 2) the number correspond to id_nb. When the idLieu = 1 i would like to show the first three, same with 2, etc...